# Issue with specifying list parameter to use with List.sum

Tags: f#, inline, f#-interactive

I'm just dabbling in F# and I'm trying to write my own simple function (in an `fsx` file, using the F# Interactive window to run it) as an exercise that will take a list of int type and return the sum of this list, using `List.sum`:

```
let sumMyList myList = List.sum myList
```

This (quite obviously) has the error

> Could not resolve the ambiguity inherent in the use of the operator `( + )` at or near this program point. Consider using type annotations to resolve the ambiguity.

So I thought I would specify the type of the `myList` parameter as `List<int>`:

```
let sumMyList myList:List<int> = List.sum myList
```

Now I have the error:

> The type `List<int>` does not support the operator `+`

The F# documentation for `List.sum` says

> `List.sum : ^T list -> ^T (requires ^T with static member (+) and ^T with static member Zero)`

I thought that the int type supported the `+` operator, and if I do

```
List.sum [1;2;3]
```

It all works correctly, as `[1;2;3]` is a `List<int>`.

What am I missing? How do I specify a parameter as being a list of int types?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing parenthesis, otherwise you are specifying the type of the return value:

```
let sumMyList myList:list<int> = List.sum myList
```

should be

```
let sumMyList (myList:list<int>) = List.sum myList
```

also you can specify this:

```
let sumMyList myList:int = List.sum myList
```

To define it in a generic way it should be declared inline:

```
let inline sumMyList myList = List.sum myList
```

Comment: Aha! I hadn't actually seen how to specify return types until your answer. As they say, a little knowledge can be a dangerous thing. Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the compiler needs to resolve which numeric operation to use when compiling `sumMyList` - it could be int, float or other (even custom) type and all of those require the compiler to generate different code.

You can specify the type using type annotations (and the answer from @Gustavo) shows all the options you have for doing this.

The other option is to mark the function as `inline`, which will make it possible to use it with different types (the compiler will inline it and then pick the actual type for each use of the function):

```
let inline sumMyList myList = List.sum myList
```

Comment: Many thanks for explaining about `inline` - I didn't know that.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that I was specifying the type completely wrong.

I suddenly had the idea of just doing

```
[1;2;]
```

and looking at it in the F# Interactive window (`Alt + #` to just run that line). It printed:

```
val it : int list = [1; 2]
```

Looks like I still had my C# head on - in F#, an int list is specified as `int list`, not `List<int>`.

I've altered my function to this:

```
let sumMyList (myList: int list) = List.sum myList
```

and it now works as expected.

Comment: Writing ``List`` with uppercase can be a problem if you have already opened the namespace for the C# List, it's better to write it with lowercase to avoid confusion.

Comment: @Gustavo - I see. My F# learning is still in its infancy, so thank you for letting me know about that.